# SmartGit: Meaning of colored checkboxes

Tags: git, smartgit

I have a red and a green colored checkbox in my SmartGit branch window. Is there any documentation about what this means?

[image]

Comment: You can't match it up with the git state of each file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox colors in the **Branches** view are corresponding to the line colors in the **Graph**. This is the **Default Coloring**. There are other colorings available from the Graph's options menu ("hamburger" menu).

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking red means some kind of error. Is there a manual about this?

Comment: There is no manual about it, but I'm wondering what could be done to make it more self-explanatory. What did you try/where did you look before posting this question?

Comment: Red as a color has a very special meaning as it most of the time indicates a problem. Before seeing it as a highlighting-color I was searching for other indications of a possible error, I did not find any and then was confused about it. If instead a more random color like blue or purple would be used before red comes into play I would have understood its meaning intuitively.

Comment: Omitting red sounds like a good idea. We are going to change this.